# Infection on a complete graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, perfect-matchings

Suppose we have a complete graph on $2n$ vertices with one "infected" vertex.

At each time step, we form a matching of the vertices. Then the vertices paired with infected vertices will also become infected.  (If both the vertices which got paired are already infected (or not infected) nothing changes, and if exactly one of the vertices is infected, both of them will become infected)

You cannot pair a vertex to a vertex that you already paired before. (This constraint seems to make the problem hard)

It's easy to see that in at most $2n-1$ time steps the whole graph is infected and if you want to infect the graph very fast, you can do it in $\approx \log n$ steps.

**Question**: But if we were to chose the matchings in a way that it takes the maximum amount of time for the whole graph to be infected, how long can we wait?

The problem seems to depend a lot on the nature of the number $2n$, the number of vertices. For instance, I have an algorithm that gives you $T=N^2-2N+1$ time steps if you start with $N^2$ vertices by splitting the graph into $N$ groups of $N$ vertices and using both matchings inside a group and externally between groups. For $2p$ vertices with prime $p$, I can get $p$ time by splitting into $p$ groups of $2$. More generally you can adapt the algorithm to any factorization of the number of vertices $2n.$ But I cannot prove if these algorithms are optimal.

Comment: is a perfect matching taken always?